# Is it possible to have two principal keys on the same navigation property in dotnet ef core?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a use case where I would like to join on two principal keys and the same foreign key on a navigation property.

Is something like this possible? I tried the following fluent configuration but it only does a left join on the last added principal key, employeeId, looks like the line .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.ManagerEID) is overridden.

```
builder.Entity<AppUser>()
  .HasMany(u => u.TeamRoles)
  .WithOne()
  .HasForeignKey(r => r.ManagerEID)
  .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.ManagerEID)
  .HasPrincipalKey(u => u.EmployeeId);
```

Is there any way to accomplish this or one has to create a second navigation collection or do a SQL query seperately?

Comment: Looks like you need two separate navigation properties.

Comment: Thank you I was hoping that there may be a way to do LEFT JOIN on both principal keys into one navigation property. I see where this may not make sense in most cases. I've since refactored my code and I'm going with a many-to-many approach. Thank you fro replying.